# How to convert code from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, parsing, converters

I have a business logic classes that are written in pure C# (without any specific things from this language) and I would convert this code into PHP. I can write my own parser, but think if I could someone did it before me.

Could you please tell me where can I find this kind of converter?

Ps. As I've written I use only plain C# programming in this language. Only arguments, declarations of variables, equations and control statements.

Comment: Since I (regrettably) voted to close this question, I hope it will eventually be migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you're hoping for someone who had experience but in case no one comes forward...

You might consider just copy and pasting the code into a PHP script and checking what breaks. Write a parser to fix that, run it across the entire script, and see what's the next thing that breaks. Continue until the script functions as expected.

If you're not using any of the more involved .Net classes I can't imagine you'll have too much trouble.

Answer (score 18):

The jsc project can convert .net/C# to PHP for you.

1. Overview: http://jsc.sf.net
2. Source: http://jsc.sourceforge.net/examples/web/OrcasAvalonWebApplication/
3. Example: http://jsc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jsc/templates/OrcasAvalonWebApplication/
   [image]

Comment: it is not clear from manual how to use this project.

Answer (score 3):

There is just started project **cs2php**. Sources are available on https://github.com/isukces/cs2php and homepage is http://www.cs2php.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking for a tool to directly convert your C# code to PHP? I doubt there is one available and I'd be a little worried about using one (from what I've learnt of C# it's not easily transferrable to PHP).

Depending on the size of the project I'd be much more inclined to rewrite it. I did have a look but couldn't find anything (lots and lots of job requests though - looks like a business there =P).

Comment: I use only basic things like as I have written. I new before writing in C# that some day I will need to translate the code to other languages too.

Comment: As long as you have fairly simple constructs, the code should translate over - it's just a matter of getting the syntax right.  PHP doesn't support all of the advanced parts of C#, but it is catching up a bit -

Answer (score 2):

You can now run your PHP code on .NET calling into your business clases using phalanger.codeplex.com

Comment: I think he wants the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I think you're probably right. Still, PHP as a view engine seems like a more elegant solution to me.

Comment: Phalanger goes both from C#->PHP and PHP->C#

Comment: @William - not in the sense that this question needs. Phalanger can communicate in both directions (C# <-> PHP), but it requires hosting the PHP within a .NET environment. What is being asked for is, is to take code written in C#, and translate it into PHP. So that it can be run in a pure PHP environment.

Comment: Maybe calling out to x-platform c# is the answer here.