# Is thare any way to translate .net C# into PHP and vice versa?

Tags: c#, .net, php, translation

Is thare any way to translate .net C# into PHP and vice versa?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441161/how-to-convert-code-from-c-to-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php), which is a .NET php compiler. If you compile php with it, you can then open the assembly in [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) to get the C# or VB.NET.

Don't know about anything that will do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The jsc project can convert .net/C# to PHP for you.

1. Overview: http://jsc.sf.net
2. Source: http://jsc.sourceforge.net/examples/web/OrcasAvalonWebApplication/
3. Example: http://jsc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jsc/templates/OrcasAvalonWebApplication/
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is going to work without getting some [wetware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetware_(brain)) involved. For example, like [this](http://softmarket.ro/freelance-jobs/auction_details/463603/c-.net-to-php-translation-md5-hash.html).