# C# to php translator

Tags: c#, php, sockets, translation, byte

Is there a C# to php translator (capable of dealing with byte operations, TCPSockets)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert code from C# to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441161/how-to-convert-code-from-c-to-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*your language* to *another language* is never extremely hard to achieve, assuming that both are Turing-complete. The real problem comes from *your framework* to *another framework*. The .NET Framework is much more capable than the PHP library. For instance, if your C# application uses threads, your PHP port is doomed.

So, no, there is no C# to PHP translator available, except real people. At least, as far as I know.

There are, however, TCP sockets in PHP, available through [`fsockopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) or the [`socket`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) extension. For byte operations, they work the same in PHP and C#.

Comment: I do 100% agree. Additionally I wouldn't translate from C# to PHP , I would do reverse because C# is much better than PHP :)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I wouldn't deem it wise to attempt this, in the interest of answering your question I'd like to nevertheless direct you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441161/how-to-convert-code-from-c-to-php/2160761#2160761). You might also find use in [this site](http://tinyurl.com/259zvk3) too. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Before i'm started searching in Google "c# to php converter online" - i know already that i will find nothing... So really, its not possible convert between frameworks. Only hand job.

Comment: he got away with saying hand job... nice