# Conversion of php block to vbnet or c#

Tags: c#, php, vb.net, code-conversion

I have this block of php that i want to convert to c# or vbnet. I am stuck on the array methods since there is no direct equal to the is array and other bits like array merge. I know that arrays behave differently in php than in c# but thats about it. I am looking online but have not found anything yet. Any ideas?

```
     private static function processArgs( $arguments )
 {
    $args = array();
    foreach ( $arguments as $arg ) {
        if ( is_array( $arg ) ) {
            $args = array_merge( $args, $arg );
        } else {
            if ( strpos( $arg, '=' ) !== FALSE ) {
                $exp = explode('=', $arg, 2);
                $args[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
            } else {
                $args[] = $arg;
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another question for the same topic [php to C# converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221669/php-to-c-sharp-converter).

See answers from @Stegi and @Number 9

Comment: @Vitaly I tried installing the php to asp.net migration tool but it does not install on w7 64 with .net 4, vs2010. I did load .net 1.1 but still nothing. Maybei have to load vs2003???

Comment: Tried, and had the same issue with installation. Not sure what installers requires also (.Net 1.1) - may be VS2003 (because it has 1.1 in it). I have 2005, 2008 - but had installation error too.

Comment: I tried installing the migration tool after i installed vs2003 still does not not install so my guess it will only install on xp. I'll try it on my workstation at some point - i'll need to bring up a virtual xp environment and try it

Answer (score 0):

c# has the `is` operator to determine data type at run time. You can use `Concat` to merge 2 arrays, you can use `String.Split` to turn a delimited string into an array. If you give more details about your inputs, we could give you more help. But this should get you close.