# Rewrite a method in C# LINQ to PHP

Tags: c#, php, linq

I want to use the following method on the server and put it in a PHP script. What does it looks like in PHP?

```
    public string Update(string data)
    {
        return data.Aggregate("", (c, a) => c + (char)(a - 1));
    }
```

Comment: If you dont want to try yourself, try some tools. SO is not a proper place for code conversions. As an input I would suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441161/how-to-convert-code-from-c-sharp-to-php

Comment: Some of the links are broken and CS2PHP needs to be installed on my server. For such a short code.. that's kind of overkilled..

Comment: Does this help? http://www.cs2php.com/how-to-begin.htm#.V5djd_l97tQ